# requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError while parsing shopify json

Tags: python, web-scraping, shopify

i,m new in python and web scraping, i write my code  trying to scrap products from shopify stores and  my code running well on all other stores  but only getting error on  https://ruggable.com/ , here is my code i,ll be thankful

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ruggable.com/collections/premium-medium-pile-rugs/products.json?limit=250&page=1'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
    }

r = requests.get(url)
product_list = []
data = r.json()
for item in data['products']:
    title = item['title']
    print(title)
    for variant in item['variants']:
        color = variant['option1']
        size = variant['option2']
        img = variant['featured_image']
        product = {
            'title': title,
            'color': color,
            'size': size,
            'imge': img

        }
        product_list.append(product)
        df = pd.DataFrame(product_list)
    df.to_csv('rugable-.csv')
    print('saved')
```

Comment: You are expecting the initial request will return you a json but it returns html file *with* json embedded in <script> tag with id `__NEXT_DATA__` - use BS4 to extract the data from inside the tag.

Comment: Another way to go is to analyse network trafic and see if you could get the data you want directly from another endpoint. In your case, you might want to fetch data from there: https://q8q4eu.a.searchspring.io/api/search/search.json?resultsFormat=native&domain=https://ruggable.com/collections/premium-medium-pile-rugs&tag=merch.segment/interested&resultsPerPage=31&siteId=q8q4eu&ajaxCatalog=v3&bgfilter.collection_handle=premium-medium-pile-rugs

Comment: thansk you but i guess it,s shopify based web and i always use this method for shopify based web

Comment: how do you approach to this endpoint .. ??